# How to get all the keyspaces in Grakn?

Tags: database, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Is there a command in the console that gives me a list of all existing keyspaces? Something like this:

```
./grakn console -list_keyspaces
```

Answer (score 2):

once inside grakn console, run

```
keyspace list
```

(from the [docs](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/running-grakn/console))

## UPDATE Grakn 2.0:

```
grakn server
```

Then in another terminal

```
grakn console
database list
```